# Send an imageview in a scrollView

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, imageview, scrollview

i have 2 .xml in one i have the resource of imageView and it is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher30005"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher22" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/bSetWall"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Imposta come sfondo"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

in another. xml i have the resource of button and also the layout where it needs to go the imageview and is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="702dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bopentx"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="tattoo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bopensax"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="sand" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bopenwx"
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:layout_gravity="left"
         android:text="wet" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bopennx"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="naked" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Bopenlx"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="loincloth" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Bopenbx"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="brazilian" />

     </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Scroll1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Linear1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="702dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

 //the image needs to go here when i click the button


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in the menu class i have used this :
public class menu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bopennx);


    button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {







        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.bopennx:
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);  
                LinearLayout  linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.Linear1);
                ImageView newImageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                newImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_brazilian1);
                linearLayout.addView(newImageView);
                break;



            }






        }});
        }
```

Comment: naturally the id of button is contained in the same. xml where do I send pictures but in a different layout

Comment: use ImageView newImageView=new ImageView(this);

Comment: the logcat tells me: unable to find resource thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain a view from a .xml that is different from the one you have set up in contentView (in your case R.layout.main), you have to inflate the xml and search the view inside the xml you've inflated.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_xml, null);  
ImageView  imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Comment: i have used this: switch (v.getId()){
  case R.id.bopennx:
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null); 
LinearLayout imageScrollLayout =(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.Linear1);
ImageView  imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);     imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_brazilian1);     imageScrollLayout.addView(imageView);
     break;

Comment: Can you please update your xml file? Do you have more than one xml file ?

Comment: yes i have another .xml, i rephrase the question so below is clearer

Comment: I'm guessing the second xml that you posted is called activity_main, what's the name of the first xml? The first xml is the one, that you want to inflate in order to get the views from it. You already have access to activity_main layout, but the class "menu" doesn't know of the other xmls in your project, that's why you need to inflate the other one, so you can call findViewById on it.

Comment: the first is where the image is contained bx.xml, and the second where there are buttons and must end where the image is activity_main.xml

Comment: ok the project does not stop at the click of the button and I think the image is recognized but to send it to the layout I used this: LinearLayout linearLayout =(LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.Linear1) ;

Comment: I will provide a propper answer tomorrow morning